# Spark can not get elements from 'MapType'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a udaf with the following buffer schema:

```
bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("grades", MapType(StructType(StructField("subject", StringType) :: StructField("subject_type", StringType) :: Nil),
      ArrayType(StructType(StructField("date", LongType) :: StructField("grade", IntegerType) :: Nil)))) :: Nil)
```

It looks like internally spark interprets the key type to be of GenericRowWithSchema instead of simple (String,String).
so Whenever I try to pull from the map :

```
  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {

var buffer_scoresMap = buffer.getAs[Map[(String,String), Array[..]](0)
```

`buffer_scoresMap.get(("k1","k2"))` returns None even though that this key is definitely in the map, I even see it in debug.
I tried to mutate the keys to `GenericRowWithSchema` and then back to `(String,String)` and then get from the map, with no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, tuples are converted into Structs and not converted back into tuples when they are part of a deeply-nested column. In other words, `buffer_scoresMap` actually has the type `Map[Row, Array[..]]`, so you can create a `Row` to fetch items from it:

```
var buffer_scoresMap = buffer.getAs[Map[Row, Array[..]](0)
buffer_scoresMap.get(Row("k1","k2")) // should not be None if key exists
```

Here's a short example that proves this:

```
// create a simple DF with similar schema: 
case class Record(grades: Map[(String, String), Array[Int]])
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(Record(Map(("a", "b") -> Array(1, 2))))).toDF("grades")

// this indeed fails:
df.rdd.map(r => r.getAs[Map[(String, String), Array[Int]]](0).get(("a", "b"))).first() // None

// but this works:
df.rdd.map(r => r.getAs[Map[Row, Array[Int]]](0).get(Row("a", "b"))).first() // Some(WrappedArray(1, 2))
```